# Xamarin iOS App Silent login failing due to non persistent token cache

Tags: ios, xamarin, access-token, adal, persistent-storage

I am developing a xamarin application for both iOS and android platforms.And I am using microsoft ADAL library for user authentication.But having a problem in acquiring token silently which will expire for every 1 hr. I am using method ***AcquireTokenSilentAsync*** to acquire the token silently (without showing login screen) in case of token expire.

Everything seems to be working in Android.However in iOS this logic is failing as the token cache stored is not persistent across app runs.Is there any way I can store the token cache permanently and achieve the same?

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages after calling `AquireTokenAsync` the first time or after calling `AquireTokenSilentAsync`? Also, have you tried it on a real device, [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/issues/21) says the simulator may not work.

Comment: AquireTokenAsync is working properly. AquireTokenSilentAsync is throwing error.Tried on real device too.Its pretty clear that in iOS the token cache is not persisting if I kill and relaunch the app, because of which the above method is failing.

Comment: I've tried by storing token cache content in some file and using the same for creating authentication context (by passing the token cache in constructor) while logging in silently, but still its of no use.

Comment: what version of library are you using? does it repro on the device or only on simulator?

Comment: Library version is 3.13.9. Checked in real device too.The cache is not persistent in case of iOS.

Comment: @Shyam Do you see the same issue with the latest [3.19.4](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/releases/tag/v3.19.4) of the library?